# Intersection of two subgroups in a factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to prove that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $A\cap B\leq K$, then $AK/K\cap BK/K = \{1\}$ in $G/K$.

I think that I have to prove that 
$$
AK\cap BK = (A\cap B)K
$$

and I thought that I could do that using the Dedekind modular law, but the only thing I've been able to state is that $$AK\cap BK = K(A\cap BK)=K(B\cap AK).$$ Is my idea right? What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you have to show. What do you mean $AK/K\cap BK/K$--that needs more grouping to make it clear.

Comment: Doesn't $(A\cap B)K = K$ since $A\cap B \leqslant K$?

Answer (score 0):

There's a theorem in group theory:

If $H,K \leqslant G,\  H \leqslant N_K$ where $N_K$ is the normalizer of $K$, then 
$$
K \unlhd HK,\\
H\cap K \unlhd H, \\
H/ (H\cap K) \approx HK/K
$$
Copied that from my notes.  Well it rings of your problem because of the $HK/K$ bit.

Now let $H := A \cap B, \ \ $.  Then clearly $H$ is vacuously contained in $N_K = G$ as given.  Then $K \unlhd HK = (A \cap B) K$, and also $H\cap K = H \unlhd H$, which gives us nothing. But lastly, 
$$
HK/K \approx H/(H\cap K) = H/H = \{H\}$$

So it seems like if you can show that $HK/K = (A\cap B)K / K \approx AK/K \cap BK/K$, then you're done since the group is isomorphic to the trivial group $\{H\}$.